# Why do we say $n$ distinct points?

Tags: geometry, soft-question, terminology

" Let's say we have $n$ distinct points... " , you see this every time you open a geometry textbook. Why not just $n$ points ? If the points are not distinct, they are not exactly $n$ points, are they ? We don't write a set as $ \{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$ where $x_1 =x_2$, or do we ? Can you give me an example of a case in geometry, where an ambiguity might arise if one does not do so ?

Comment: Who says we are talking about sets?

Comment: @MarcinŁoś I am speaking very naively. A set whose elements are these points.

Comment: There are people who feel like distinctness should be assumed, and then there are people who feel the opposite way. Writing it this way avoids confusing a member of either group.

Comment: Exactly. It could mean set, it could mean, say, sequence. It's not clear from the context.

Comment: There are certainly theorems that don't need to assume that in a collection of N points, none of the points share coordinates.  Whether you consider that really M points for some M < N and simply have a point sharing multiple names or multiple points sharing coordinates doesn't matter - you still need some way to express those proofs.  In general, you don't ever want to assume more conditions than are needed for a proof.

Comment: Actually, we do write sets $\{ x_1, x_2, x_3 \}$ where $x_1 = x_2$. For example, one sometimes defines an ordered pair $(a,b)$ to be the set $\{ \{ a \}, \{ a, b \} \} $, and we mean this for *all* pairs of objects $a$ and $b$, not just for pairs of distinct objects. And thus $$(a,a) = \{ \{ a \}, \{ a, a \} \} = \{ \{ a \}, \{ a \} \} = \{ \{ a \} \} $$

Comment: @rschwieb Indeed, the very same person to write "$n$ distinct points" might two pages later write "$n$ not-necessarily distinct points".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is done to clearly state that the points are distinct.

Note that it is not written that we have a **set** of $n$ points and
so without writing that the points are distinct it may be interpreted
that the statement being made is of the form 
$$
\forall p_{1},p_{2},...,p_{n}:\text{[statement]}
$$

where the $p_{i}$ can be any points, without the restriction that
they are different.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to points in relation to curves (as well as to eigenvalues and to zeros of polynomials) neither *set* nor *sequence* conveys the right idea. The concept needed is that of *bag*: a set with an associated multiplicity for each element. For example, consider the points where two algebraic curves of degree $n_1$ and $n_2$ intersect. Typically there are $n_1n_2$ points of intersection (including complex values). But, in special cases, some of these points coincide, where the curves are tangent or have multiple crossings; the number of coincident points indicates the order of tangency or multiple intersection. If we only consider the points as a set, we have fewer then $n_1n_2$ of them, and information about where the tangencies or multiple crossings lie is lost. If there are $n$ points, and no tangency or multiple intersection is involved, we might say "$n$ points of single multiplicity". But this is making rather a meal of it; saying "$n$ distinct points" sounds lighter.

Answer (score 1):

Because, in the following discussion,
the actual number of points occurs
and needs to be referred to.

For example, 
it might say
"Let the points be
$(P_i)_{i=1}^n$."